# SCROLLBAR X no trabaja y SCROLLBAR Y si en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

tengo este código que necesito colocar un scroll vertical y uno horizontal, sol se ha creado el vertical pero el horizontal se crea pero no trabaja, estoy pasando una hoja de un archivo excel que tiene 8 columnas y es mucho mayor su ancho que la ventana que se esta usando en tkinter, por esto necesito el scrollbar horizontal, pero este a pesar de que se crea esta en colo gris como des habilitado. Gracias por su ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.title ('ejemplo')
root.pack_propagate(False)  
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.resizable(0,0)

frame1= Frame(root,width=1000,height=500)
frame1.grid(column=0,row=0)

tv1= Treeview(frame1,height=22)
tv1.grid(column=1,row=0)

treescrolly = Scrollbar(frame1,orient=VERTICAL,command=tv1.yview)
treescrolly.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='ns' )

treescrollx = Scrollbar(frame1,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=tv1.xview)
treescrollx.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='we')

tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set,yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)

estilo= Style(frame1)
estilo.theme_use('clam')
estilo.configure(".",font=('Arial',8), foreground='black',background='orange')
estilo.configure('Treeview',font=('Arial',8),foreground="black", background="white")
estilo.map('Treeview', backgroundg=[('selected','yellow')],foreground=[('selected','white')])

df = pd.read_excel ('./ErlangB.xls','Ant',)
tv1['column'] = list(df.columns)
tv1['show'] = "headings"


for columna in tv1["column"]:
    tv1.heading(columna,text=columna)

df_fila=df.to_numpy().tolist()
for fila in df_fila:
    tv1.insert('', 'end',values=fila)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro pero quizás la configuración en los ejes esté mal, puedes intentar lo siguiente.

Para la malla:

```
tv1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Eje y:

```
treescrolly.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
```

Eje x:

```
treescrollx.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
```

Por último la conf de la malla:

```
tv1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tv1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Recuerda la referencia cardinal en X de izquierda a derecha East-West

Comment: Estos cambios los probé pero no tienen ningún efecto, con tus observaciones tengo la figura 1, mientras que con el cambio como estaba antes el programa tengo al figura 2, en este caso por lo menos el eje Y tiene accesibilidad correcta, pero el eje X es como que se fuera hasta el final del archivo sin poder tener el scrollbar.  Las figuras las voy a poner en la descripción del problema.

Comment: @JorgeZambrano si quieres dejar un comentario, agrega las imágenes como enlace en los comentarios o edita tu pregunta para añadir más información. No edites las respuestas de otros usuarios para proporcionar información adicional.